# Ionic 4/Angular Removing Error From Other Field

Tags: angular, ionic4, formbuilder, customvalidator

I have two date fields in a form `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. Each field has validation where `dateFrom` cannot be later than `dateTo` and `dateTo` cannot be earlier than `dateFrom`.

Here is the code:

```
this.detailsForm = formBuilder.group({
    dateFrom: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    dateTo: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
},
{
    validator: Validators.compose([this.validatesFromDate, this.validatesToDate])
});

validatesFromDate(c: AbstractControl) {
    if(!c.get('dateFrom').value || !c.get('dateTo').value )
    {
        return null;
    } 
    else
    {
        if(new Date(c.get('dateFrom').value) > new Date(c.get('dateTo').value))
        {
            c.get('dateFrom').setErrors({ valid: false});
            return;
        }
    }
}

validatesToDate(c: AbstractControl) {
    if(!c.get('dateFrom').value || !c.get('dateTo').value )
    {
        return null;
    } 
    else
    {
        if(new Date(c.get('dateTo').value) < new Date(c.get('dateFrom').value))
        {
            c.get('dateTo').setErrors({ valid: false});
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say these are the default dates:

dateFrom = 16/10/2019

dateTo = 17/10/2019

If I was to change `dateFrom` to 18/10/2019, it is now later than `dateTo` and it should set an error which it does. The field get's set to invalid by angular and I have an error message that appears underneath `dateFrom` and `dateTo` essentially has the same.

```
<ion-row *ngIf="!detailsForm.controls.dateFrom.valid">
    <ion-col>
        <ion-text class="error" color="danger">
            This date cannot be later than the other.
        </ion-text>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row *ngIf="!detailsForm.controls.dateTo.valid">
    <ion-col>
        <ion-text class="error" color="danger">
            This date cannot be earlier than the other.
        </ion-text>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

If I then change `dateTo` to 20/10/2019 which is now later than `dateFrom` it should ideally clear the error in the `dateFrom` field but it doesn't.

I have tried setting this at the start of each validation function:

```
c.get('dateFrom').setErrors({ valid : true });
c.get('dateTo').setErrors({ valid : true });
```

The same for the `dateTo` field too so that it resets the validation first before setting an error again if it doesn't validate but it doesn't seem to remove the error. The error message is still there and the field is still invalid.

Am I missing something or am I not doing something right?

Comment: why only has an unique error, when the dateTo>dateFrom? This error is an error of the Form, and show near dateTo `*ngIf="detailsForm.invalid"`. This has the apparence that the only error is the dateTo

Comment: @Eliseo Each field has it's own error message but I've just included 1 and said that the other is pretty much the same. I've added it now so it's clear

Comment: I try explain better in the answer: An uniq error, an unique validator over the form, the error near the input dateTo

Answer (score 0):

My idea is an unique error in dateTo:

```
<!--see that the error ask about detailsForm.valid 
       not about controls.dateTo.valid-->
<ion-row *ngIf="!detailsForm.valid"> 
    <ion-col>
        <ion-text class="error" color="danger">
            This date cannot be earlier than the other.
        </ion-text>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean? I've just tried it and it just displays the errors immediately? That's with `c.get('dateFrom').setErrors({ valid : true });` but if I don't have that, it doesn't appear immediately which is good and it sets both fields an error if the validation fails which is fine but it still doesn't clear the error

Comment: it's only Angular, but https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h14xqk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html